# jQuery navigation menu using setTimeout, mouseenter, mouseleave

Tags: jquery, settimeout, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm having trouble spotting an issue where [this jQuery menu](http://jsfiddle.net/wonderkernel/d8Vtz/7/) breaks when hovering between the three main tabs. The menu works if i hover in, then hover all the way out before selecting another tab...
I think the problem may have to do with scope of a variable (called "n" in the jQuery) or the setTimeout() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `var n = ...` instead of just `n = ...` to create a local variable.

The way you're currently accessing the `n` variable, as a string being evaluated after the timeout, requires a global variable, however. It's better if you define it as a function that can draw upon variables from the local scope:

```
setTimeout(function() { $(n).hide(); }, 150);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLXsx/)

Comment: @won: hmm, I'm not sure I follow... in my example it's a local variable in all cases...?

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was in response to your answer before you included the second paragraph/demo. Thanks!